# Using Twitter Search API with a specific metadata

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

I've been using the Twitter API (with Python) for quite some time, but I'm unable to search for Twitter users having a specific criterion. For example, the API has several user attributes in the user JSON data it returns, like `statuses_count` or `profile_link_color`. But how do I do a reverse search using such parameters, like searching for users who have tweeeted more than 1000 times, or users who have created their accounts last week?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/search), it looks like you can search for users that fulfill certain criteria with a `GET users/search` query:

> Provides a simple, relevance-based search interface to public user
>   accounts on Twitter. Try querying by topical interest, full name,
>   company name, location, or other criteria.

Comment: Thanks, but I saw that very part of documentation before posting here. Their examples do not demonstrate searching by any specific key.

Comment: [Here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) is the list of full queries supported by the Twitter Search API; if it's not on this list, I doubt they support it.

Comment: @FiscalTwinkle this search API is for tweets, not for users. The [user search API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/search), as I mentioned before, doesn't contain such example queries.

Comment: Tweet and user searches use the same query parameter structure @SamChats.